# Ansible Find files and loop through each one

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use the find function using shell in my ansible playbook, get the results and for each file returned loop through them and decrypt them. I am having a hard time figuring out why it fails though or how to loop through the individual files.

```
  - name: Find Encrypted Files
    shell: find . -type f -name "*.enc.yaml"
    register: enc_files

 - debug:
      msg: "{{ Files.stdout_files }}"
```

This will output the following

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
       list of files
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is loop through it here:

```
  - name: Decrypt .yaml config files
    shell: sops --decrypt {{ item }}.enc.yaml > {{ item }}.yaml
    with_items: enc_files
```

But when trying to do so I get the following error:

```
failed: [localhost] (item=enc_files) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "sops --decrypt enc_files.enc.yaml > enc_files.yaml", "delta": "0:00:00.073051", "end": "2021-03-31 17:14:23.890518", "item": "enc_files", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 100, "start": "2021-03-31 17:14:23.817467", "stderr": "Error: cannot operate on non-existent file", "stderr_lines": ["Error: cannot operate on non-existent file"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or if there is a better method of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
name: Decrypt .yaml config files
    shell: sops --decrypt {{ item }} > {{ item }}.yaml
    with_items: enc_files.stdout_files
```

Because it appears the item is including the extension.

Comment: I overlooked that. I tried that but got this error

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: [AnsibleUndefined]. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}

Comment: Your debug msg was still the same?

Comment: Actually I think I updated this to get the list and not the dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I went about this a bit differently, see my results below:

```
- name: Decrypt files
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    working_directory:  "{{ playbook_dir }}"
    Enc_Files: []

  tasks:

    # - name: Checkout Master and Pull
    #   shell: git checkout master && git pull

    - name: Get all .enc.yaml Files
      find:
        paths: "{{ working_directory }}"
        patterns: "*.enc.yaml"
        recurse: yes
      register: files

    - name: Adding Encrypted Files to list
      no_log: True
      set_fact:
        Enc_Files: "{{ Enc_Files + [item.path] }}"
      with_items: "{{ files.files }}"

    - name: Decrypt .yaml config files
      shell: sops --decrypt {{ item }} > {{ item | regex_replace('(enc.yaml)', 'yaml') }}
      with_items: "{{ Enc_Files }}"
```